# Is a private static field guaranteed to be non null when accessed from a static method if initialized in the private constructor

Tags: java, static, initialization

I have a class named `UrlController` The method is like:

```
public class UrlController {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.site.mil/";       

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    private UrlController() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Should I check `if(retrofit==null)` in the `getRetrofit()` method or it's that always not null?

Comment: why would you need to check? it can be null, it can also be another value.

Comment: Are you trying to do factory method?

Comment: u should have to implements check on target type which consumes return statements.

Comment: I wanna check if ``retrofit`` is null, instantiate another ``Retrofit`` and return that

Comment: @manikant gautam why?

Comment: Why are you creating the statically linked instance in a constructor and not a static initializer block?

Comment: return ((retrofit!=null)?retrofit:new_object)

Comment: @Thomas my bad! you're right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing can construct `UrlController` (except `UrlController` because your constructor is `private`) so `retrofit` is guaranteed to be `null`. I think you wanted a *`static` initializer*. Something like,

```
static {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: will I be able to return ``Retrofit`` instance from ``getRetrofit()`` with the insurance that instance will not be null?

Comment: The `static` initialization block will run when `UrlController` is loaded; if your Builder returns a `null` then the instance will be `null`. It might also be a good idea to mark the `retrofit` reference as `final`.

Comment: you guys rock! Don't know why I didn't catch that idea.

Comment: This code is equivalent to just writing `public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()`.

Answer (score 5):

Since the method `getRetrofit` is `static`, hence it can be called, even when the object of the class has not been created.

Hence, you must check for it.

But even if you don't check, the method will return `null`. So you must check for null where you call this method.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to create a Singleton?

Because right now you have a private constructor which can only be called within the class. So your retrofit field will always be null. Furthermore you probably want to use something like this:

```
public final class UrlController {
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.site.mil/";     
private static volatile Retrofit instance;

private UrlController() {
    instance = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

 public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (UrlController.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new UrlController();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

With that you can simple call `UrlController.getInstance()` and you will never get a null by that.